# Dropdown of Months with Simple_Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I am trying to build a dropdown select input of months using simple_form. However, I am having trouble figuring out where to even begin. Currently, it is a text input area:

```
<%= f.input :start_month %>
```

I need to know what arguments to pass in order for this to be a dropdown of all 12 months. It is not important for it to return an integer value for the months but would be ideal in the event I use it for ordering later on.

I am still a beginner with rails and could really use the help on this one. I can provide any extra information necessary.

**Edit:**

I would like the dropdown to show the month names, not simply numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this:

```
<%= f.input :start_month, :collection => 1..12 %>
```

or with month names:

```
<%= f.input :start_month, :collection => ['January','February',...,'December'] %>
```

Comment: How would I configure it so it would display month names? I suppose I should have added that to the question.

Comment: Thank you! This works. This is somewhat unrelated but where would I put an array of the months to refer to whenever I used a month dropdown?

Comment: You will need a helper to return the array

Answer (score 11):

Here is my solution:

```
<%= f.input :start_month, collection: (1..12).map{|i| [I18n.t("date.month_names")[i], i]} %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= f.select :month, Date::MONTHNAMES.compact.each_with_index.collect{|m,i| [m,i]}, prompt: 'Month'
```

Comment: Problem with this is: index starts at 0.

Comment: thats not for use with simple_form.  the other answers have `f.input`.  and ditch the `compact`.  reason = previous comment